# OpenCV FlannBasedMatcher gives different result when using for one pair image matching and when using for couple of pair image matching

Tags: c++, opencv, surf, flannbasedmatcher

I want to find a template image on some scene images. So I try to find `Homography` between scene images and template image. I'm using `OpenCV` and `c++`. First using `SURF` to find descriptors for image and template. Then using `FlannBasedMatcher` to get matches point.
everything seemed to be good, but when I run this program just for each image lonely, result is different with when I run it for all scene images.

```
Ptr<FlannBasedMatcher> matcher = FlannBasedMatcher::create();
vector<DMatch> matches;
matcher->match(objectDescriptor, sceneDescriptor, matches);
double max_dist = 0, min_dist = DBL_MAX;

for (int i = 0; i < objectDescriptor.rows; i++)
{
    double dist = matches[i].distance;
    if (dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
    if (dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
}

vector< DMatch > goodMatches;
for (int i = 0; i < objectDescriptor.rows; i++)
{
    if (matches[i].distance < max((coeffGoodMatches * min_dist), maxDistanceMatches))
    {
        goodMatches.push_back(matches[i]);
    }
}

vector<Point2f> obj;
vector<Point2f> scene;
for (int i = 0; i < goodMatches.size(); i++)
{
    //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
    obj.push_back(keypoints_object[goodMatches[i].queryIdx].pt);
    scene.push_back(keypoints_scene[goodMatches[i].trainIdx].pt);
}
Mat H = findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC);

Mat result;
warpPerspective(img_scene, result, H, img_object.size(), WARP_INVERSE_MAP);
```

The key points and descriptors which find by `SURF` is same for each scenario, but when `FlannBasedMatcher` try to match descriptors, result is different.
I also try to clear `FlannBasedMatcher` like below, but result is the same without clear.

```
matcher->clear();
```

Any idea?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Did you resolve it?